# explore the site not found with hostname

Tags: host-named

error from powershell : 
***Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy'***

***I tried to install "Charles " to figure out the web request, it is amazing that everything go well suddenly, but if I　uninstall  Charles, it stil can not work.***

I can enter sharepoint site with the url like befor:

```
http://psalab-sp2013:26531
```

```
http://psalab-sp2013:41003
```

But now

I enter url

```
http://psalab-sp2013:41003
```

this it the SharePoint Central Admin page ,but it showed:

Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

When I replace "paslab-sp2013" with "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", I enter the SPCA site, but the others sites I have created  still can not enter with "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" or "psalab-sp2013",

even with my local ip address.

Is anyone knows the reason ? I have checked bindings in IIS and host file, no configuration related with "psalab-sp2013" on a right machine with SP 2013

How do you think ?

I cannot find any mapping configuration in host file and bindings in IIS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the sites in IIS are started.. and try to ping them, see if they point to the right IP.

Comment: Yes, it has been started, you know when I enter "http://psalab-sp2013:41003" it cannot access, but if I enter "localhost:41003", I can access.
But I ping http://localhost:41003 and ping http://psalab-sp2013:41003, they all failed

Comment: Try pinging psalap-sp2013 .  do you get the right IP?

Comment: Yes, it works as ping "psalab-sp2013" details:
Pinging PSALAB-SP2013.PSALAB.NET [fe80::6de0:4d43:66c5:f7d%11] with 32 bytes of
data:
Reply from fe80::6de0:4d43:66c5:f7d%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::6de0:4d43:66c5:f7d%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::6de0:4d43:66c5:f7d%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::6de0:4d43:66c5:f7d%11: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::6de0:4d43:66c5:f7d%11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: I try powershell cmd "get-spsite" in a work machine, it show all sites, but the same cmd in this error machine does not work, it occurs:
get-SpSite : Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url: http://psalab-sp2013/sites/appdeploycmd.

Comment: if just using cmd : get-SpSite, error is:
get-SpSite : Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section.

Comment: I tried to install "Charles " to figure out the web request, it is amazing that everything go well suddenly, but if I　uninstall  Charles, it stil can not work.

Comment: I deploy a sharepoint hosted app,the url is <pre>http://app-d6ca8dc432b351.apptestdomain/sites/app/SharePoint_Hosted_Hello_App/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fpsalab%2Dsp2013%2Fsites%2Fapp&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=0&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4420%2E1017&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp%2Dd6ca8dc432b351%2EAppTestDomain%2Fsites%2Fapp%2FSharePoint%5FHosted%5FHello%5FApp</pre> if I access from the psalab-sp2013(error machine) it still not find, but I access from another work machine in the same domain with the url, it access the app successfully.